# MSB6006 error when code used to work fine in visual studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, xtensor

I'm getting the 'MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code 2' error. The problem is that my code used to work fine. The issue came when I tried to add another library from xtensor (the xtensor-blas) and I couldn't get it to work correctly. I just erased everything I tried to add and get a clean run, but it now fails every time.

While trying to compile the Error List says things like "C1083 fatal error: cannot open source file: 'files that I have deleted'". Whenever I stop the build, it then only gives the MSB6006 error.

It has become extremely frustrating since my code is identical to what it used to be and now doesn't work.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: C1083 appears when your project file references a `.cpp` file that doesn't exist. Edit and clean up said project file.

Comment: The project files used to be part of the project, then I deleted them and excluded their folder from the project. There are no references to those files in the code, there just used to be.

Comment: Well the reference has to come from *somewhere*. Just open your `vcxproj` file inside a text editor and remove the references manually if VS screwed up.

Comment: Just found it, and yea the references are in there. Will just erasing them and saving potentially screw anything up?

Comment: Nah, MSBuild is not *that* picky. You've got version control anyway, don't you ;)

Comment: Looks like it worked, thanks. I'll have to take some time and learn about all of the files Visual Studio makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by Quentin: There may still be references in the `vcxproj` file created by Visual Studio. Delete those references and it should work.